# Best way to fill textbox with list of values by double click using java script or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fill a textbox with list of values just by double click on it using java script or j query?

Eg:- I have a list of 10 users and i want to fill a textbox control like a dropdownlist just by clicking on it using java script or j query.

Is it possible than how?

Comment: what is a "textbox" ? a select list ? or something else ? can you share your HTML code ?

Comment: textbox is a control input type text not select list

Comment: @RomeshSomani what is the HTML output you are expecting ? ie can you should how the HTML will look if the function you want works correctly

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript binding of the `dblclick` event :

```
element.ondblclick = function() { 
    alert("double click"); 
};
```

[Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.ondblclick)

jQuery binding of the `dblclick` event :

```
$(element).dblclick(function() {
    alert('double click');
});
```

[Docs here](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)